# Manually setting the status value of the status value in the fineuploader object

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using the scalling function to send two smaller images while enabling the hideScaled:true.

This is working fine but the issue is when deleteing a file the itemLimit option is not working correct.

I understand why and I want to know if I can manual set the groupId ids to "deleted" when I delete an image from the API.

I did not see anywhere I could call the API to set the status so I could set that all three items had been delete when they only clicked the delete option for the image being displayed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot manually change the internal status for files.  If you want all items in the group to be reported as deleted, then you will need to actually delete them via the API.  See the deleteFile API method for details.

Comment: Thanks. I figure out how to do this.

Also I found a custom work around on controlling the number of images that we allow the person to upload.